# Notation for a countable collection of elements from the product of two uncountable sets

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

My background is engineering but I realize the details are very important in mathematics. I would like to understand the subtleties in the following notation. Let $X,Y\subset \mathbb{R}$ (they could be open or closed, countable or noncountable). I define the product of $X$ and $Y$ as, $P=X Y= \{xy, x\in X,y\in Y\}$. My first question is: Is this different from Cartesian product? My feeling is it should be because (3,5) and (1,15) are considered to be different in Cartesian product but not in my definition. My second question is with P defined as above, now I want to form a set $\Theta$ of all possible countable sums of elements in P. I can think of two ways to write that set, which are as follows. Is either of them correct? Are they the same or different?

$1.\;\;\Theta=\left\{\sum_{i=1}^mx_iy_i\in\mathbb{R}|\mid m\in \mathbb{N},x_i\in X, y_i\in Y\right\}$.

$2.\;\;\Theta=\left\{ \sum_{i=1}^m\{xy\}_i \in \mathbb{R}\mid m\in \mathbb{N},x\in X, y\in Y\right\}$

Comment: One is points are numbers, one is points are ordered pairs.  That's already different.

Comment: Second point:  what does the notation $\{xy\}_i$ mean?

Comment: Third point:  those sums are finite, not countable.  And since they're finite, you don't need $\pm \infty$.

Comment: The notation $X\times Y$ is dedicated to the cartesian product. Your $P$ should rather be denoted by $XY$.

Comment: @Randall Thank you so much for the first part of the question. With $\{xy\}_i$ I am trying to denote an element in P, which has two parts $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$.  I guess it does not work. Does the first expression of $\Theta$ describe my set correctly?

Comment: @Anne Bauval Thank you. I will fix it.

Comment: (1) is reasonable except that as Randall mentioned, you'll never get $\pm\infty$ since each sum is finite. I'd write it as $\left\{\sum_{i=1}^m x_i y_i|m\in\Bbb N,x_i\in X,y_i\in Y\right\}$.

Comment: @Karl  Thank you both ( Karl and Randall) so much. Let me just make sure I am understanding you correctly. Since my $m\in \mathbb{N}$, $m$ is finite. Thus, these are all finite sums of real numbers. Therefore, I could never get anything infinite. Am I correct?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can split your question of notation in two:

- $P=XY=\{xy\mid x\in X,y\in Y\}$, and
- $\Theta=\{\sum_{i=1}^mp_i\mid m\in\Bbb N,p_i\in P\}$, or better $\{\sum_{i=1}^mp_i\mid m\in\Bbb N\text{ and }\forall i\in\{1,\dots,m\}\;p_i\in P\}$, which can be abridged as $\{\sum_{i=1}^mp_i\mid m\in\Bbb N\text{ and }p\in P^{\{1,\dots,m\}}\}$.

Note that $\pm\infty$ must be avoided for the elements of $X$ and $Y$, not only for the definition of $\Theta$ (risk of indeterminate form $(+\infty)+(-\infty)$), but already for the definition of $P$ (risk of indeterminate form $0\cdot\infty$).

This was for finite sums. But if you want countable sums, you must include the convergence condition in the choice of the $p_i$s, like this:
$$\left\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty p_i\mid\forall i\in\Bbb N\;p_i\in P\text{ and the series }\sum_{i=1}^\infty p_i\text{ is convergent}\right\}$$ or equivalently:
$$\left\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty p_i\mid p\in P^{\Bbb N}\text{ and the series }\sum_{i=1}^\infty p_i\text{ is convergent}\right\}$$
or
$$\left\{s\in\Bbb R\mid\exists p\in P^{\Bbb N}\;\lim_{n\to\infty}p_i=s\right\}.$$
With this last notation, you can even allow series which diverge to $\pm\infty$:
$$\left\{s\in\overline{\Bbb R}\mid\exists p\in P^{\Bbb N}\;\lim_{n\to\infty}p_i=s\right\}.$$

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much. I can see the way you describe the sets are  the most clear descriptions. For the finite sums, can I say my first expression is equivalent to your first expression? (I admit yours is a better expression. I used mine somewhere and I want to know if I have made a mistake.)

Comment: Yes it is. No mistake.

Comment: Thank you so much. I learned a lot from your answers.